# Firebase hosting throws error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, importerror, firebase-hosting

I am trying to host a website using `firebase-hosting` and I am getting the error:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

It happens in `script.js:1`. The source code looks like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';

callWs();
console.log('This worked now!');

async function callWs() {
    try {
        const res = await axios(
            `https://us-central1-jpabiggmbh-001.cloudfunctions.net/realexData?amt=${500}&curr=${'CHF'}`
        );
        console.log('This function ran just now!');
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
    console.log(res);
}
```

My folder structure looks like this (focus on the public tree):

[image: Files in Firebase project folder]

I'm calling the script in the `index.html`:

```
<head>
  <title>Fantastic title</title>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
```

My `firebase-functions` imports work fine but I have a `package.json` file there and I assume this is one reason why I am having trouble?

My `firebase.json` file looks like this:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming from line `1` which contains the code:

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

This is an [ES Module import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) statement. Native module support in browsers is still pretty new. Firefox just started shipping this [May 9, 2018](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/60). You need to make sure you are using a browser that [supports modules](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module).

When you load a module script you need to [tell the browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script).

```
<script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
```

Another issue is the `from` value `'axios'`. Browser have no knowledge of npm packages and package names so you have to specify a location.

```
import * as axios from '/node_modules/axios/dist/axios.min.js';
```

or

```
import * as axios from 'https://unpkg.com/axios@0.18.0/dist/axios.min.js';
```

`import` from `packageName` is a shorthand tooling uses to refer to locally installed dependancies.

Since you are running `import` within a script it is considered a [dynamic import](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/dynamic-import). Dynamic imports are only shipped in Chrome currently and have a different syntax.

```
import('https://unpkg.com/axios@0.18.0/dist/axios.min.js')
  .then(axios => {
    axios.get(...);
  });
```

Ultimately you are trying to use a technology that's not quite ready for use. I would recommend looking into adding a build step with something like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/).

Comment: Thank you for that extensive reply, very helpful! I have a follow up question concerning firebase, given that they only support static content, would that play a role as well?

Comment: You can actually serve [Functions through Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions). If you were writing functions in TypeScript you could use your original imports in the Functions but you wouldn't be able to serve the JS files to users.